# If statements with passed variables

Tags: php

Basically I'm grabbing a variable from the url and I need to send the user to custom pages based on what state they fill in. i.e. if it's one of the coverred states, they'll get sent to custom pages...but if it's any other state they get sent to the standard one.

I'm guessing it's just a simple if statement with an else...but for some reason I can't get it to work properly.

```
<?php
$state = urlencode($_GET['state']);
if ($state=="california"){$link = "http://website.com/page1";}
else if ($state=="new york"){$link = "http://website.com/page2";}
else if ($state=="ohio"){$link = "http://website.com/page3";}
else  {$link = "http://website.com/default";}
header("Location: $link");
?>
```

Is this right or should I be doing something else?

Comment: What doesn't work? Despite the minor problems noted in the answers, your code should work. `urlencode()` of a string with no special characters should be a no-op.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need urlencode function to encode what you "GET", unless you sent the string in the url has been encoded. However, in that case you would need the urldecode function, still not urlencode.

So your code should be like this:

```
<?php
$state = $_GET['state'];
//or $state = urldecode($_GET['state']); 
//if you are receving an encoded url.
if ($state=="california"){$link = "http://website.com/page1";}
else if ($state=="new york"){$link = "http://website.com/page2";}
else if ($state=="ohio"){$link = "http://website.com/page3";}
else  {$link = "http://website.com/default";}
header("Location: $link");
?>
```

Also, check the 'state' in the url. Did you receive the correct string that you need? Try to echo $state, and see what you get.

Answer (score 1):

The `urlencode` is not needed and even introduces a bug (you will never match strings such as `"new york"`, because `urlencode` will turn `$state` into `"new+york"`).

Other than that the code looks OK. Just remove it and you 'll be good.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `urlencode`

```
<?php
    $state = $_GET['state'];
        if ($state=="california"){
              $link = "http://website.com/page1";
         } else if ($state=="new york") {
              $link = "http://website.com/page2";
         } else if ($state=="ohio"){
             $link = "http://website.com/page3";
         } else {
             $link = "http://website.com/default";}
                  header("Location: $link");
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is tidier to do this with `switch`, and combine the repeated stuff:

```
switch($_GET['state']) {
    case "california": $page = "page1"; break;
    case "new york": $page = "page2"; break;
    case "ohio": $page = "page3"; break;
    default: $page = "default"; break;
}
header("Location: http://website.com/".$page);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use an associative array; this is attractive if there are lots of choices.

```
$statemap = array('california' => 'page1',
                  'new york' => 'page2',
                  'ohio' => 'page3');

$state = $_GET['state'];
$link = 'http://website.com/' . array_key_exists($state, $statemap) ? $statemap[$state] : 'default'
header("Location: $link");
```